# change background and text of strips associated to multiple panels in R / lattice

Tags: r, plot, lattice

The following is the example I work on.

```
require(lattice)
data(barley)
xyplot(yield ~ year | site, data = barley)
```

[image]

I want to put different strip color for different sprips and font color is also different optimized with the backgroud color. For example:

```
strip background colors = c("black", "green4", "blue", "red", "purple", "yellow")
font color = c("white", "yellow", "white", "white", "green", "red")
```

Rough sketch of the first one is provided:
[image]
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a clean and easily customizable solution.

`myStripStyle()`, the function that is passed in to the `strip=` argument of `xyplot()` uses the counter variable `which.panel` to select colors and also the value of `factor.levels` for the panel that's currently being plotted.

If you want to play around with the settings, just put a `browser()` somewhere inside the definition of `myStripStyle()` and have at it!

```
bgColors <- c("black", "green4", "blue", "red", "purple", "yellow")
txtColors <- c("white", "yellow", "white", "white", "green", "red")

# Create a function to be passed to "strip=" argument of xyplot
myStripStyle <- function(which.panel, factor.levels, ...) {
    panel.rect(0, 0, 1, 1,
               col = bgColors[which.panel],
               border = 1)
    panel.text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5,
               font=2,
               lab = factor.levels[which.panel],
               col = txtColors[which.panel])
}    
xyplot(yield ~ year | site, data = barley, strip=myStripStyle)
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

It might not be wise to refer to variables outside of the scope of the function.

You could use `par.strip.text` to pass additional arguments to the strip function. `par.strip.text` can be defined at the plot level and is generally used for setting text display properties, but beeing a list you can use it to bring your variables to the strip function.

```
bgColors <- c("black", "green4", "blue", "red", "purple", "yellow")
txtColors <- c("white", "yellow", "white", "white", "green", "red")

# Create a function to be passes to "strip=" argument of xyplot
myStripStyle <- function(which.panel, factor.levels, par.strip.text,
                     custBgCol=par.strip.text$custBgCol,
                     custTxtCol=par.strip.text$custTxtCol,...)     {
    panel.rect(0, 0, 1, 1,
            col = custBgCol[which.panel],
            border = 1)
    panel.text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5,
            font=2,
            lab = factor.levels[which.panel],
            col = custTxtCol[which.panel])
}
xyplot(yield ~ year | site, data = barley,
        par.strip.text=list(custBgCol=bgColors,
                            custTxtCol=txtColors),
        strip=myStripStyle)
```