# changing background color in xyplot()

Tags: r, lattice

I'm trying to get the background colors of the strips to change (it is a 6 by 6 matrix and i have 6 strip colors stocked in a vector named cola). I've tried to combine things found on the internet, but the result i get i completely off the mark: for now all i get is that the vertical strips are all yellow and the horizontal ones all red :(

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
B<-structure(list(ylab = c(0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 
-1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), xlab = c(0, -1.02679909743483, -4.31389840050087, 
-4.72016163070677, -3.82773068058066, -4.95060796675797, 1.02679909743483, 
0, -3.28709930306604, -3.69336253327194, -2.80093158314584, -3.92380886932314, 
4.31389840050087, 3.28709930306604, 0, -0.406263230205904, 0.486167719920203, 
-0.636709566257106, 4.72016163070677, 3.69336253327194, 0.406263230205904, 
0, 0.892430950126108, -0.230446336051202, 3.82773068058066, 2.80093158314584, 
-0.486167719920203, -0.892430950126108, 0, -1.12287728617731, 
4.95060796675797, 3.92380886932314, 0.636709566257106, 0.230446336051202, 
1.12287728617731, 0), zlab = c(1, 0.435981356312883, 1.28746578953454e-08, 
1.64728897189548e-09, 9.04719004157784e-08, 1.22124532708767e-15, 
0.435981356312883, 1, 2.30452944283144e-07, 1.23923277972615e-07, 
1.38063360011209e-06, 7.7715611723761e-16, 1.28746578953454e-08, 
2.30452944283144e-07, 1, 0.654543666603895, 0.608788895482761, 
3.33066907387547e-16, 1.64728897189548e-09, 1.23923277972615e-07, 
0.654543666603895, 1, 0.0429030453016164, 0, 9.04719004157784e-08, 
1.38063360011209e-06, 0.608788895482761, 0.0429030453016164, 
1, 4.22994972382185e-14, 1.22124532708767e-15, 7.7715611723761e-16, 
3.33066907387547e-16, 0, 4.22994972382185e-14, 1), g1 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("1", "2", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor"), 
    g2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ylab", 
"xlab", "zlab", "g1", "g2"), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
mycol<-c("light grey", "light grey", "purple", "purple", "purple", "purple", 
"light grey", "light grey", "purple", "purple", "purple", "purple", 
"light green", "light green", "light grey", "light grey", "light grey", 
"purple", "light green", "light green", "light grey", "light grey", 
"light green", "purple", "light green", "light green", "light grey", 
"purple", "light grey", "purple", "light green", "light green", 
"light green", "light green", "light green", "light grey")

mycola <- rainbow(6)


useOuterStrips(bwplot(~B$ylab|B$g1*B$g2,ylab="",xlab="",as.table=TRUE, par.settings=list(strip.background=list(col=mycola)),panel=function(...,bg){
    panel.fill(col=mycol[panel.number()])
},strip = function(..., bg) {
     strip.fill=col[which.packet()]
   },scale=list(draw=FALSE)))
```

Comment: If I understand correct, you would like assign different colors to each element of the horizontal and vertical strips? Currently, you can set the color of all the horizontal strips, but not individually.

Comment: yes, this is what i want to do. Would you then know how i can remove the strips altogether? I'll try to color/resize the outer row/col of the matrix then

Comment: +1 Thanks for the interesting question and especially for the reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code (quickly adapted from my answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536239/change-background-and-text-of-strips-associated-to-muliple-panels-in-r-lattice/8537752#8537752)) gets you part of the way to a solution. (I'd be interested to learn whether/how it can be adapted to also print text in the each of the strips).

One thing to note is that the customized strip function need to be passed directly to `useOuterStrips()`, rather than to the nested call to `bwplot()`.

```
# Create a function to be passes to "strip=" argument of xyplot
myStripStyle <- function(which.panel, factor.levels, ...) {
    panel.rect(0, 0, 1, 1,
               col = bgColors[which.panel],
               border = 1)
    ## This call to panel.text() commented out because it does not
    ## work as I would have expected/hoped it to
    # panel.text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5,
    #            font=2,
    #            lab = factor.levels[which.panel],
    #            col = "black")
}

mycola <- rainbow(6)
bgColors <- mycola

useOuterStrips(bwplot(~B$ylab|B$g1*B$g2,ylab="",xlab="",as.table=TRUE,
                      panel=function(...,bg){
                          panel.fill(col=mycol[panel.number()])
                      },
                      scale=list(draw=FALSE)),
               strip = myStripStyle,
               strip.left = myStripStyle)
```

[image]