# How can I change the color of the header in a xyplot?

Tags: r, lattice

I am using xyplot from the lattice package, and I want to change the color of hte header. Currently, it is an ugly light-orange color.

```
library(lattice)

x <- c(1:10, 1:10)
y <- c(10:1, 10:1)
z <- c(1:10, seq(1,20, by=2))
a = c(rep("one",10),rep("two",10))
DF <- data.frame(x, y, z, a)
xyplot(y ~ x | a, groups = z < 5, data = DF, col = c("black", "red"),
 pch=20, cex=0.3)
```

Comment: I really like **lattice** but also dislike some of its default settings. Fortunately, it makes it easy to supply your own themes (i.e. lists of settings that can be passed in to `par.settings=`). For a few examples of what's possible, install the **latticeExtra** package and then run `library(latticeExtra); example("custom.theme")`. For spatial data, the **rasterVis** package provides several additional themes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to reset the contents of `trellis.par.get()$strip.background$col`.

To do this for a single plot, use the `par.settings=` argument:

```
xyplot(y ~ x | a, groups = z < 5, data = DF, col = c("black", "red"),
       pch = 20, cex = 0.3, 
       par.settings = list(strip.background=list(col="lightgrey")))
```

To more persistently reset the strip background color, use `trellis.par.set()`:

```
trellis.par.set(strip.background=list(col="lightgrey"))
```

To see how you might have found this out yourself, try the following:

```
names(trellis.par.get())
trellis.par.get("strip.background")
```

Finally, for an example of more complicated (and aesthetically appalling) strip-background manipulations, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536239/change-background-and-text-of-strips-associated-to-muliple-panels-in-r-lattice/8537752#8537752).