# Changing the colour of a strip text based on a condition

Tags: r, lattice

I want to change the color of the text in a panel strip for a lattice plot, based on a condition.
Let's assume I'm working on the following dummy dataframe and scatterplot:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(
    x = c("AV","DZ"),   
    y=rep(c(letters[1:4]),5), 
    stringsAsFactors = F))
df$z <- rnorm(20)
df$q <- rnorm(20)
plotter <- function(dataframe) { xyplot(q ~ z | y, data=dataframe)}
charts <- dlply(df, .(x), plotter)
charts
```

I want to set the `par.strip.text` color variable `col` equal to `"red"` if the mean of `df$q` is less than zero, `"blue"` otherwise.
How would you suggest to proceed? I've tried something like `if-else` condition, but I felt lost after a few attempts.

On a more general note, I'd really appreciate any suggestion on how highlighting some panels based on conditions in a multipanel plot like this.

**EDIT**
The difference with the question that was already answered is that I need to use `xyplot` in combination with `dlply`, to plot on several pages. Following the example above, one page for each value of `x`, conditioning on `y` (I've edited the code to reflect more accurately the situation).
Now, if I want to change the color of the strip background (as usefully suggested in the comment), should I pick the value of the color from a list as well? Should I use a list of vectors? A dataframe?
Let's suppose that the four panel colours should be the following:

```
[1] "blue"  "red"   "blue"  "green"
```

How would you suggest to modify the `myStripStyle` function proposed in the link?

Comment: [This might help get you started](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8537752/980833).

Comment: Josh, thank you so much!!! 
Sometimes searching the archives without a good keyword is far worse than others... I'll study the example, it seems exactly what I needed.

Comment: Oh good. Glad to hear that helped!