# Change background of strips in R / lattice with dlply function

Tags: r, plyr, lattice

I need to use xyplot in combination with dlply, to plot on several pages. Following the example below, one page for each value of x, conditioning on y:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(
    x = c("AV","DZ"),   
    y=rep(c(letters[1:4]),5), 
    stringsAsFactors = F))
df$z <- rnorm(20)
df$q <- rnorm(20)
plotter <- function(dataframe) { xyplot(q ~ z | y, data=dataframe)}
charts <- dlply(df, .(x), plotter)
charts
```

Now, if I want to change the color of the strip background (as usefully explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8537752/980833)), should I pick the value of the color from a list as well? Should I use a list of vectors? A dataframe? A combination of `x` & `y` values? Two nested `plyr` functions? 
Let's suppose that the four panel colours should be the following:

```
"blue"  "red"   "blue"  "green"
```

How would you suggest to modify the `col` parameter in the `myStripStyle` function (proposed in the link) that follows?

```
bgColors <- c("black", "green4", "blue", "red", "purple", "yellow")
txtColors <- c("white", "yellow", "white", "white", "green", "red")
# Create a function to be passed to "strip=" argument of xyplot
myStripStyle <- function(which.panel, factor.levels, ...) {
panel.rect(0, 0, 1, 1,
col = bgColors[which.panel],
border = 1)
panel.text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5,
font=2,
lab = factor.levels[which.panel],
col = txtColors[which.panel])
}
```

To be honest, I think that this question could have already been answered somewhere else, but I couldn't find any mix of `plyr` functions and `lattice` graphics that could help me to change parameters in this way.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack and somebody with experience in `lattice` should really add a proper answer. But this will do what you desire, so here it goes. You can specify `allLevels` in the global environment. Then you recalculate `which.panel` within `myStripStyle` using the global variable `allLevels`.

```
allLevels <- levels(df$y)
# Create a function to be passed to "strip=" argument of xyplot
myStripStyle <- function(which.panel, factor.levels,  ...) {
  # recalculate which.panel based on allLevels
  which.panel <- match(factor.levels, allLevels)[which.panel]
  panel.rect(0, 0, 1, 1,
             col = bgColors[which.panel],
             border = 1)
  panel.text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5,
             font=2,
             lab = allLevels[which.panel],
             col = txtColors[which.panel])
}
plotter <- function(dataframe) { xyplot(q ~ z | y, data=dataframe, strip=myStripStyle)}
# 
dlply(df, .(x), plotter)
```

Comment: Thansk shadow, I got your hack and it's indeed useful to start thinking about a solution. But as usual things are a little more complex than what dummy dataframes show...  
My levels are a combination of two factors. let's say `y` and `v` so the real plotter function woul be like this  
`plotter <- function(dataframe) { xyplot(q ~ z | y+v, data=dataframe, strip=myStripStyle)}`  
How would you change `allLevels` and subsequently (I think) `which.panel` function?

Comment: Note that in this case also `plotter(df)` does not work anymore (only colors by `y`). I don't really understand the `lattice` `strip` argument, so I really cannot help you. But it's probably best to ask a new question about extending `myStripStyle` to the 2-dimensional case. Adding something along the lines of `allLevels = expand.grid(levels(df$y), levels(df$v))` with appropriate solution for `which.panel` should then be fairly simple.