# changing strip's color in lattice multipanel plot with 2 (or possibly more) factors

Tags: r, lattice

I've checked quite extensively through the forum and on the web but I couldn't find anyone that already presented my case, so here you are the question:

my goal: **how can I extend the example presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536239/change-background-and-text-of-strips-associated-to-muliple-panels-in-r-lattice/8537752#8537752) in case I have more than one conditioning factor?**

I've tried several ways to modify the `which.panel` variable of `strip.default` function, but I couldn't come out of my problem.

This is the code I'm using at the moment (**with comments**):

```
if (!require("plyr","lattice")) install.packages("plyr","lattice")
require("plyr")
require("lattice")

# dataframe structure (8 obs. of 6 variables)
data2 <- structure(list(
  COD = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L),  
                  .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"),
  SPEC = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
                   .Label = c("15/25-(15/06)", "15/26-(22/06)"), class = "factor"), 
  DATE = structure(c(16589, 16590, 16589, 16590, 16589, 16590, 16589, 16590), class = "Date"), 
  PM.BDG = c(1111.25, 1111.25, 1141.29, 1141.29, 671.26, 671.26, 707.99, 707.99), 
  PM = c(1033.14, 1038.4, 1181.48, 1181.48, 616.39, 616.39, 641.55, 641.55), 
  DELTA.PM = c(-78.12, -72.85, 40.19, 40.19, -54.87, -54.87, -66.44, -66.44)), 
  .Names = c("COD", "SPEC", "DATE", "PM.BDG", "PM", "DELTA.PM"), 
  row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")

# create a dataframe with a vector of colors 
# based on the value of DELTA.PM for the last 
# date available for each combination of COD and SPEC.
# Each color will be used for a specific panel, and it will
# forestgreen if DELTA.PM is higher than zero, red otherwise.
listaPM <- ddply(data2, .(COD,SPEC), summarize, ifelse(DELTA.PM[DATE=="2015-06-04"]<0, "red", "forestgreen"))
names(listaPM) <- c("COD","SPEC","COLOR")

# set a personalized strip, with bg color based on listaPM$COLOR 
# and text based on listaPM$COD and listaPM$SPEC 
myStripStylePM <- function(which.panel, factor.levels, ...) {
  panel.rect(0, 0, 1, 1,
             col = listaPM[which.panel,3],
             border = 1)
  panel.text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5,
             font=2,
             lab = paste(listaPM[which.panel,1],listaPM[which.panel,2], sep=" - "),
             col = "white")}

# prepare a xyplot function to plot that will be used later with dlply.
# Here I want to plot the values of PM.BDG and PM over time (DATE), 
# conditioning them on the SPEC (week) and COD (code) factors.
graficoPM <- function(df) {
  xyplot (PM.BDG + PM ~ DATE | SPEC + COD,
          data=df,
          type=c("l","g"),
          col=c("black", "red"),
          abline=c(h=0,v=0),
          strip = myStripStylePM
  )}

# create a trellis object that has a list of plots, 
# based on different COD (codes)
grafico.PM  <- dlply(data2, .(data2$COD), graficoPM)

# graphic output, 1st row should be COD "A", 
# 2nd row should be COD "B", each panel is a different SPEC (week)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
print(grafico.PM[[1]], position=c(0,0.5,1,1), more=TRUE)
print(grafico.PM[[2]], position=c(0,0,1,0.5))
```

As you can see, the first row of plots is correct: text of the first strip is "A" (1st COD), the weeks (SPEC) are shown and the color represents if PM is above or below PM.BDG on the last date of the plot

On the contrary, the 2nd row of plots just repeats the same scheme of the first row (as it can be seen by the fact that COD is Always "A" and 2nd strip's bg color in the 2nd row is green, when the line of PM in red is clearly well below the PM.BDG line in black).

Although I'd like to keep my code, I'm pretty sure my goal could be achieved with a different strategy. If you can find a better way to use my dataframe, I'll be happy to study the code and see if it works with my data.

Comment: Please share your data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (data with spaces in the values isn't easy to copy/paste into R). Also include the code you used to actually draw the plot. Try to make the description of the problem self-contained.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, I edited the post. Hopefully this should provide all the info needed for a possible analysis.

Comment: This still seems confusing. You're defining a `data` variable but your `ddply()` calls reference `data2` which has a column `DELTA.PM` not in `data`. Then your plotting code references the data frame as `df`. Is this as simplified as you can make it to reproduce your problem? At the very least post code that can be copy/pasted into R and will run.

Comment: Sorry MrFlick, you are definitely most right! My fault, I had to make up a simplified version of the data frame (that is BIG) and I missed a few things. I edited the code again, and this time I tested it: it works. There is only one issue I didn't touch: I referenced the data frame as `df` in the plotting code, but then in the call to the function I specify that `df` is actually the object `data2`. It could be done differently, but it works fine.

Comment: @MrFlick is there any other issue with the code, or is the question still unclear? I would appreciate any help that could suggest where to look for a possible solution...

Comment: While to code is now runnable, it's not exactly minimal. I still can't figure out what you are trying to do. You didn't really describe the goal of the code. I don't know what "first three plots" you are referring to. When I run the code, plots appear and quickly disappear in the graphics device. I don't see any strips with the text "A"

Comment: @MrFlick ok, I see your points. I've edited again the text of my question, and the code (inserting more comments and trying to simplify it even more). It's not minimal, but to explain in detail the way I'm working i don't think it could be much less than that. Thanks for bearing with me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is match up the current panel data to the `listaPM` data. Because you are doing different sub-setting in each of the calls, it's difficult to use `which.panel()` to match up the data sets.

There is an [undocumented feature](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Accessor-functions-in-lattice-graphics-td3609435.html) which allows you to get the conditioning variable names to make the matching more robust. Here's how you would use it in your case.

```
myStripStylePM <- function(which.panel, factor.levels, ...) {
  cp <- dimnames(trellis.last.object())
  ci <- arrayInd(packet.number(), .dim=sapply(cp, length))
  cv <- mapply(function(a,b) a[b], cp, as.vector(ci))

  idx<-which(apply(mapply(function(n, v) listaPM[, n] == v, names(cv), cv),1,all))
  stopifnot(length(idx)==1)

  panel.rect(0, 0, 1, 1,
             col = listaPM[idx,3],
             border = 1)
  panel.text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5,
             font=2,
             lab = paste(listaPM[idx,1],listaPM[idx,2], sep=" - "),
             col = "white")
}
```

When run with the rest of your code, it produces this plot

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. I've tried to substitute my function `myStripStylePM` with yours but it gives the following error `length(idx) == 1 is not TRUE` as soon as I try to print the graph. Is there anything I missed (again)? I've tried to remove that line and I get what you posted...

Comment: Ah, i left off a `which()`. I've updated the solution. That line is really there to warn you if a panel cannot be uniquely tied to a row of your data.frame.

Comment: this works. Although I was trying to achieve the very same thing with the same logic, I admit that my knowledge of r language is far beneath the level of your solution. From what I can understand of it, it is already quite generalizable. Would you mind commenting a little more your code?