# How can I change the color, and the sub titles (Winter, Summer) of this figure in R?

Tags: r, plot

```
glmtom  <- glm(Organic.Matter ~ Season*Bay, data = nuttom)
tefftom <- allEffects(glmtom)
plot(tefftom, ylab = "Mean Organic Matter [%]", main = "GLM Organic Matter")
```

[image]

Comment: this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536239/change-background-and-text-of-strips-associated-to-muliple-panels-in-r-lattice/8537752#8537752

Comment: super helpful, many thanks